# Desabilitar Scrollbar de um Form MDI Container

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-basic-6, mdi

Alguém sabe como impedir que os Child Forms fiquem se movendo alem da tela e exibindo um scrollbar?

Gostaria que houvesse um limite para mexer os Child Forms... Que eles movessem somente até o tamanho da tela e não passassem disso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não quero scrollbars no formulário principal.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me corrija se estiver errado, mas para desativar você pode seguir essas tentativas:

- Tem algum controle dentro da forma que está estendendo o tamanho dela, ou é maior que a própria janela.
- Mude a propriedade `AutoScroll` para **False**.
- Mude a propriedade `AutoScaleMode` para `Dpi`.
- Mova alguns controles para um local visível na janela.

Não resolveu? Achei esse modelo nesse [arquivo](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?499963-RESOLVED-Scroll-Bars-MDI-Form). Tente o seguinte:

**1. Declare essa função**

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function ShowScrollBar(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wBar As Integer, ByVal bShow As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

**2. Declare o método Wnd**

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If mdiClient IsNot Nothing Then
        'Oculta as barras
        ShowScrollBar(mdiClient.Handle, SB_BOTH, 0)
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

**3. Declare esse campo**

```
Private mdiClient As MdiClient = Nothing
```

**4. Coloque isso no método de inicialização da sua classe inicializadora**

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
   'Procura os clientes MDI na sua janela

    If TypeOf c Is MdiClient Then
       mdiClient = CType(c, MdiClient)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: CypherPotato, a sua dica funcionou cara! ^_^

Porém há um problema na visualização... Os scrollbars ficam piscando como um lag ou algo do tipo quando o mdichild passa pelos cantos...

Acho que a solução seria atribuir a janela dos Mdichilds como None e assim impedir a movimentação delas... Parece ser a melhor opção

Comment: Você também pode criar um Timer, com `interval` definido para 1 milissegundo, que ao fazer o evento `Timer1.Tick` pode restaurar o local duma MdiChild para um objeto `System.Drawing.Point` (Local) fixo, daí quando o usuário tentar move-la ela irá voltar para o local do Timer. Fica a dica ;)